# vagrant ssh does not connect to vm on windows 10

Tags: database, shell, vagrant, virtual-machine, git-bash

[EDIT] I uninstalled both vagrant and virtualbox. I had virtualbox version 5.0 and latest version of vagrant, now I have the latest version of both(virtual box 6.0.1) , i tried same regular steps and the same undesired output showed up.

**vagrant** does not connect to *vm** on Windows 10
my vagrant ssh output:  *"VM must be running to open SSH connection. Run `vagrant up`\nto start the virtual machine."*

I found on search engine that vm for windows 10 is bugged and here is official
debugging page https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/9027
I tried it and didn't work for me.

However, these may work for someone else:
1- `$vagrant --debug ssh` 
*undesired output*: check [screenshot](https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501665682263)
the last line is: INFO interface: Machine: error-exit ["Vagrant::Errors::VMNotRunningError", "VM must be running to open SSH connection. Run `vagrant up`\nto start the virtual machine."]

2- `$vagrant up; vagrant ssh`
*undesired output*: "VM must be running to open SSH connection. Run `vagrant up`\nto start the virtual machine."

3- `$vagrant provision`
*undesired output*: ==> default: VM is not currently running. Please, first bring it up with `vagrant up` then run this command.

4- I followed the steps mentioned here https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1007131
and restarted pc then ran vagrant ssh again,
*undesired output*: VM must be running to open SSH connection. Run `vagrant up`
to start the virtual machine.

also tried: vagrant up; vagrant ssh (just in case there is other issues like time out?)
undesired output: VM must be running to open SSH connection. Run `vagrant up`
to start the virtual machine.

5-finally 
A- `vagrant destroy` 
      B- `vagrant up`
      C- `vagrant ssh`
*undesired output*: VM must be created before running this command. Run `vagrant up` first.

I expect the output to be a **successful connection** between vagrant and vm.
like this output  [this output](https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501665915980) done by Carl

My vagrant file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # NOTE: This will enable public access to the opened port
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine and only allow access
  # via 127.0.0.1 to disable public access
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   apt-get update
  #   apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
```

Comment: What is the content of your vagrant file?

Comment: I included it in the question body @AndreiLupuleasa

Comment: This is a VirtualBox error, it's not specific to Vagrant. See also [VirtualBox machine starts, but not running](https://superuser.com/questions/1018443/virtualbox-machine-starts-but-not-running) (though that's for Linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a temporary solution:

I turned on the virtualbox application while running the commands `vagrant up` and `vagrant ssh`
I dont know if this is the perfect solution yet but I will update this answer when I finish my task and reboot the machine and find everything is working.

`vagrant ssh` output:

> Welcome to your Vagrant-built virtual machine. Last login: Fri Sep 14
>   06:23:18 2012 from 10.0.2.2 vagrant@precise64:~$

See the following 3 apps running

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens all the time for me too in Windows.

The only solution I have found is more of a workaround.

Launch VirtualBox and then run **vagrant ssh** and it seems to come up fine until I restart the computer. I don't know why.